# How to run code even if the app is closed

Tags: flutter, dart, background-service

Can an flutter app still run code even if the app is closed? I am trying to build an application that notifies a user even if the app is closed. Hoping for answers. TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default you would have to integrate your background service on a platform specific way.

But I found this package that handles the native integration mostly for you: [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service).

```dart
final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      // this will executed when app is in foreground or background in separated isolate
      onStart: onStart,

      // auto start service
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      // auto start service
      autoStart: true,

      // this will executed when app is in foreground in separated isolate
      onForeground: onStart,

      // you have to enable background fetch capability on xcode project
      onBackground: onIosBackground,
    ),
  );
  service.startService();
```

Code snippet taken from the package example [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service/example).

How to add the package to your project:

1. Open your `pubspec.yaml` file
2. Add `flutter_background_service: ^2.4.3` to your `dependency` section
3. Run `flutter pub get`

Comment: Is it working on iOS when the app is terminated?

Comment: @selimdogan The plugin requires additional setup to run on iOS (See https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service#ios). Theoretically it should but I haven't tried it myself.